# Where get database path in database open helper?

Tags: android, database

I try to get the database path in the constructor of database helper class like this:

```
public DB_Nabege_helper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBname, null, 1);
    Nabege_context = context;
    DBpath=Nabege_context.getDatabasePath(DBname).getPath();
}
```

When run app : crashed app

```
    10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nabproduct.nabege/com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath(ContextWrapper.java:231)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at com.nabproduct.nabege.DB_Nabege_helper.<init>(DB_Nabege_helper.java:44)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity.<init>(Collection_List_Activity.java:165)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-15 16:41:37.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
```

I add  more code as an answer.

Comment: attach logcat details

Comment: attach your database helper class also

Comment: I add more codes in one answer

Comment: Sergey Glotov : What is your mean of  'call it' ?

Comment: Looks good for me, in my test App the same code is working. Did you try to clean and completely rebuild your project? Can you post the code where you instanciate your Helper class? And please variable names start with lowercase character

Comment: @programmer138200 I mean, where do you create DB helper and what do you pass to constructor as context parameter.

Comment: I call createdatabase  in oncreate  method of main activity and I don't pass anything with context . I clear the Nabege_context and replace with context

Comment: @programmer138200 You should pass something. DB helper constructor has parameter: `DB_Nabege_helper(Context context)`.

Comment: Sergey Glotov : I create object of this class in my activities like this :-------------------->private DB_Nabege_helper nabege_db = new DB_Nabege_helper(this);      ----------   Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from the stacktrace that you create DB helper in the activity constructor or field initializer possibly. In both cases activity isn't initialized yet (moreover you don't need to override activity constructor in the most cases). Move DB helper assignment inside the activity `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I want get and assign database path in DB helper class

Comment: @programmer138200 problem is not in database path, problem is in wrong context.

Comment: I use this code in oncreate method of my activity : ------>>>nabege_db = new DB_Nabege_helper(this);  ---- and it worked. Thank you for answering